# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file with npm start -- -e=stag -c=it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, nvm

when i run the below command

```
npm start -- -e=stag -c=it
```

I get this error:

```
./scripts/start.js -e=stag -c=it

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens when you put in fewer options?

Try omitting the --

Try omitting that and all the other options